# How to tune random forest code for quality prediction

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics, random-forest

I am new to machine learning.I have got this dataset - http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Wine+Quality. I have to predict Quality of wine which is the last column on the dataset.I thought about applying Neural network or random forest for this, where as NN gave around 55% accuracy, with random forest I managed to get 73% so far. I want to improve the accuracy further.Below is code I have written.

```
wineq <- read.csv("wine-quality.csv",header = TRUE)
str(wineq)

wineq$taste <- ifelse(wineq$quality < 6, 'bad', 'good')
wineq$taste[wineq$quality == 6] <- 'normal'
wineq$taste <- as.factor(wineq$taste)
set.seed(54321)
train <- sample(1:nrow(wineq), .75 * nrow(wineq))
wineq_train <- wineq[train, ]
wineq_test  <- wineq[-train, ]

library(randomForest)

rf=randomForest(taste~.- 
quality,data=wineq_train,importance=TRUE,ntree=100)

rf_preds = predict(rf,wineq_test)
rf_preds
table(rf_preds, wineq_test$taste)
```

Output:

> table(rf_preds, wineq_test$taste)

```
rf_preds bad good normal
bad    302   11     81
good     7  163     36
normal  93  101    431
```

If I want to use `tuneRF` it gives me below error:

```
   fgl.res <- tuneRF(x = wineq[train, ], y= wineq[-train, ], 
   stepFactor=1.5)
```

> Error in randomForest.default(x, y, mtry = mtryStart, ntree =
>   ntreeTry,
>          : 
>          length of response must be the same as predictors

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass to `tuneRF` the feature variables as `x` and the response variable as `y`.

So, first find the column position of your response variable (`taste`):

```
resp_pos <- which(colnames(wineq) == "taste")
```

Then:

```
fgl.res <- tuneRF(x = wineq[train, -resp_pos ], y= wineq[-train, resp_pos], 
   stepFactor=1.5)
```

I noticed also that you use `wineq$taste <- ifelse(wineq$quality < 6, 'bad', 'good')` to find your "new" response (`taste`), based on the column `quality`. Note that this is perfectly fine, but you need to remove the column `quality` before training.

If you don't do this, your model will be overly optimistic, since it'll pick up that for example:

`quality < 6` will always mean `taste=="bad"`